# How to connect to other system Database?

Tags: sql-server, vb6

Using VB6 and SQL Server 2005

I want to write a sql connection for connecting  to other system sql server.

Code

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=STAR;Data Source=" & SName & ""
```

In SName - Am giving a Server Name

The Above connection code is working for the same system, Suppose I want to connect to other system database means

For example

I run the program in system A, the Database in system B. How to write a sql connection

```
Is possible with IP Address like SName = 192.12.12.1/System B
```

How to Write a connection string.

Need Code Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your network / DNS, you should be able to enter the machine name, you may also need a domain name.

SQL Server also has something called Named Pipes for accessing a SQL instance by it's name - do a google search on that...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an IP address or a machine name but not both. The exact syntax is

`Data Source=192.12.12.1; Initial Catalog=STAR; User Id=abc; Password=def;`

In case, you have a trust established between the two servers, then you can replace the `User Id` and `Password` part by using `Integrated Security=True` just like you are doing if the database and program exist on the same machine.

Various types of connection strings are discussed here: http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005